# How to do update-alternatives --config without having an interactive prompt?

Tags: c++, linux, github, gcc, github-actions

So I'm trying to run these commands in the Github Actions environment:

`sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`

`sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`

to change the threading model to POSIX, but it brings up the following prompt:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (providing /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc).

  Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32   60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32   60        manual mode
```

How do I answer this without having access to the shell? I have tried giving 1 as a command (didn't work), and these:

`echo "1" > sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`

`echo "1" > sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`

But after I use `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` to check, the prompt still shows the selection being at 0. (If you change the alternatives manually, it should remember your choice)

What do I do? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change value of compiler priorities, you can simply change 30 to 90(or any other value that is bigger than 60), so `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix` will became your auto compiler.
If this aproach is sutable for you, do something like this

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 60
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix 90
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

Answer (score 10):

First check which values you can set using

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --list x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32
```

Now choose one of the values with `--set`. For example:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32
```